# A question and reference about Bombieri's article continued fraction of algebraic numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, collatz-conjecture

Above the Comments in the article [continued fraction of algebraic numbers](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/book/papers/vdp/BombieriPoorten_CFofAlgNumbs.pdf),  there are some words on the unboundedness/cycle of coefficients of continued fraction of algebraic numbers "Thus, contrary to received wisdom, there may well be ‘a formula’ for the continued fraction expansion of an algebraic number of degree greater than 2. However, such a formula does not necessarily usefully increase our understanding of the nature of the partial quotients of such a number. To make that manifest one notes that the notorious $3x + 1$ problem is readily recast as a similar, but simpler formula
$x_{h+1} = (1+x_h − 2\lfloor x_h/2\rfloor)x_h − \lfloor x_h/2\rfloor$ with $x_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$

John Conway has shown that it is undecidable whether general games of this sort are unbounded or cycle".

Also it is known that Prof. Kurtz in U of Chicago has a similar proof about generalized $3x+1$.

My question is, has John Conway proven it is undecidable whether games of this sort are unbounded or cycle? Any reference for the proof?

Comment: I believe it is known that the Game of Life is undecidable, whether it was done by Conway or not. As it stands your question is quite vague, I would suggest rewording it so that a precise mathematical question can be discerned.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao,, the reference of Conway by Bombieri's article ? This requirment is  not vague.

Comment: So, you just want a reference to Conway's paper? The paper, "Unpredictable iterations", is available at https://gwern.net/doc/cs/computable/1972-conway.pdf Lagarias writes about Conway's work at https://par.nsf.gov/servlets/purl/10276329 Bibliographic details on Conway's paper:  J. H. Conway, Unpredictable iterations, Proceedings of the Number Theory Conference (University of Colorado, Boulder, CO, 1972, pp. 49–52.

Comment: I believe they are talking about Conway's undecidable generalization of Collatz conjecture, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Undecidable_generalizations). This has nothing to do with the Game of Life.

Comment: Conway's paper was reprinted at pp. 219–223 of Jeffrey C. Lagarias, editor. The Ultimate Challenge: The 3x + 1 Problem, American Mathematical Society, 2011. There's also a later paper of Conway,  J. H. Conway, On unsettleable arithmetical problems, Amer. Math. Monthly 120 (2013), no. 3, 192–198. So, XL, is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thank you for your comment, I have asked Mr. Bombieri but have not gotten reply.

Comment: @Wojowu,  thank you for your comment.

Comment: It is not clear to me, just what you have asked Professor Bombieri. If what you want to know is, what work of Conway did Bombieri have in mind, I believe the papers I mentioned are the only ones in which Conway dealt with these issues. A Conway bibliography is available at https://web.math.princeton.edu/WebCV/ConwayBIB.pdf (but it's not complete). Here's a better bibliography: https://zbmath.org/?q=ia%3Aconway.john-horton and here's another one: https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/suppl/10.1098/rsbm.2021.0034

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thank you so much, I ask Prof. Bombieri about  what work of Conway did Bombieri have in mind.

Comment: I guess John Conway has not proven what Prof. Bombieri says what John Conway has proven.

Comment: Conway didn't prove that for all iterations of that sort it is undecidable whether they are unbounded, or have cycles. In particular, he proved nothing about the Collatz iteration. But he did prove that there exist iterations of that sort for which it is undecidable etc., etc. And it's possible that the Collatz iteration is one of the undecidable ones. You can read the Conway paper, and see for yourself exactly what he proved.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.03562                        terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2020/02/collatz.pdf